# git,curl,wget redirect to localhost

Tags: python, sockets

Git gives me this error:

```
$ git clone How people build software · GitHub
Cloning into 'xxxx'... fatal: unable to access 'xxx (Michael Dungan) · GitHub': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443: Connection refused
```

`curl` also gives the error:

```
$ curl http://baidu.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

`wget` also gives the error:

```
$ wget http://baidu.com
Error parsing proxy URL “ http://127.0.0.1:8123 ”: Scheme missing.
```

But `ping` is okay:

```
ping http://baidu.com
PING http://baidu.com (180.149.132.47): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 180.149.132.47: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=24.689 ms
64 bytes from 180.149.132.47: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=23.770 ms
64 bytes from 180.149.132.47: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=25.112 ms
```

And my browser is okay.

I have restarted my Mac, closed my proxy, VPN, but the it never changes. This problem appears after I write this python code:

```python
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection
socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this problem, i hava missed the http_proxy,https_proxy system environment variable in `/.bash_profile`. remove them, it is okay now.